# Cuda - 3D block & grid dimension confusion - Another one

Tags: c++, cuda

In the following simple example, I'm allocating memory on the device using `cudaMalloc3D`, and incrementing every voxel of my 3D data by one, which works fine, as long as I'm using symmetric 3D volumes.

Host Code looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    typedef float PixelType;

    // Set up test data
    dim3  image_dimensions = dim3(32, 32, 32);
    size_t num_elements = image_dimensions.x * image_dimensions.y * image_dimensions.z;
    PixelType *image_data = new float[num_elements];
    for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        image_data[i] = float(i);
    }

    // Allocate 3D memory on the device
    cudaExtent volumeSizeBytes = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(PixelType) * image_dimensions.x, image_dimensions.y, image_dimensions.z);
    cudaPitchedPtr devicePitchedPointer;
    cudaMalloc3D(&devicePitchedPointer, volumeSizeBytes);
    cudaMemset3D(devicePitchedPointer, 1.0f, volumeSizeBytes);

    // Copy image data from the host to the device
    cudaMemcpy3DParms copy_params_host_to_device = {0};
    copy_params_host_to_device.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr((void *)image_data, sizeof(PixelType) * image_dimensions.x, image_dimensions.y, image_dimensions.z);
    copy_params_host_to_device.dstPtr = devicePitchedPointer;
    copy_params_host_to_device.extent = volumeSizeBytes;
    copy_params_host_to_device.kind   = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
    cudaMemcpy3D(&copy_params_host_to_device);

    // Kernel Launch Configuration
    dim3 threads_per_block = dim3(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 blocks_per_grid = dim3((image_dimensions.x + threads_per_block.x - 1) / threads_per_block.x, (image_dimensions.y + threads_per_block.y - 1) / threads_per_block.y, (image_dimensions.z + threads_per_block.z - 1) / threads_per_block.z);
    extract_patches_from_image_data<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(devicePitchedPointer, image_dimensions);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Copy image data back from the device to the host
    cudaMemcpy3DParms copy_params_device_to_host = {0};
    copy_params_device_to_host.srcPtr = devicePitchedPointer;
    copy_params_device_to_host.dstPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr((void *)image_data, sizeof(PixelType) * image_dimensions.x, image_dimensions.y, image_dimensions.z);
    copy_params_device_to_host.extent = volumeSizeBytes;
    copy_params_device_to_host.kind   = cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost;
    cudaMemcpy3D(&copy_params_device_to_host);

    // Check image data
    for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Element: " << i << " - " << image_data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // Free Memory
    cudaFree(devicePitchedPointer.ptr);

    delete [] image_data;
}
```

The corresponding kernel for incrementing all values:

```
__global__ void extract_patches_from_image_data(cudaPitchedPtr devicePitchedPointer, dim3 image_dimensions)
{
    // Index Calculation
    int x = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y + blockDim.y * blockIdx.y;
    int z = threadIdx.z + blockDim.z * blockIdx.z;

    // Get attributes from device pitched pointer
    char     *devicePointer  =   (char *)devicePitchedPointer.ptr;
    size_t    pitch          =   devicePitchedPointer.pitch;
    size_t    slicePitch     =   pitch * image_dimensions.y;

    // Loop over image data
    if(z < image_dimensions.z)
    {
        char *current_slice_index = devicePointer + z * slicePitch;

        if(y < image_dimensions.y)
        {
            // Get data array containing all elements from the current row
            PixelType *current_row = (PixelType *)(current_slice_index + y * pitch);

            if(x < image_dimensions.x)
            {
                current_row[x] = current_row[x] + 1.0f;

                // Get values of all all neighbors
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As long as I keep my `image_dimensions` symmetric, e.g. (32, 32, 32), everything works fine. When I'm trying to use (32, 32, 33), it works fine until voxel 33759, the following values remain the same. My question now is how I should adapt my code in order to use non-symmetric data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would recommend doing [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with CUDA code, although it won't sort out the issue here.
2. You are passing a  `float` to `cudaMemset3D`.  If it's your intention to set each float quantity to this value, that won't work.  cudaMemset3D works like the host `memset` function.  It takes a `unsigned char` value and sets `unsigned char` quantities.  You cannot use this method to properly initialize a `float` value to 1.0f.  But this is also not the crux of your problem.
3. You're not using the `make_cudaPitchedPtr` function correctly. Please review the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g47a7d89a9b1361212ac4ac3998670e0d).  Your last two parameters should be the `x` and `y` dimensions respectively, not `y` and `z`.  You have two instances of this in your code.

I was able to get your code to run correctly with the modification to the two uses of `make_cudaPitchedPtr`